# The right way to compare a System.Double to '0' (a number, int?)

Tags: c#, compare

I have this `if` expression,

```
void Foo()
{
    System.Double something = GetSomething();
    if (something == 0) //Comparison of floating point numbers with equality 
                     // operator. Possible loss of precision while rounding value
        {}
}
```

Is that expression equal with

```
void Foo()
{
    System.Double something = GetSomething();
    if (something < 1)
        {}
}
```

? Because then I might have a problem, entering the `if` with e.g. a value of 0.9.

Comment: `// Comparison of floating point numbers with equality  // operator.`  Did you really need to specify that? :)

Comment: Heck no. There are a hell of a lot of values between 0 and 1. Why not just test it and see for yourself?

Comment: I just wrote the same as Resharper did, to show where my focus is.

Comment: @Charles: Also, there are a lot of numbers that are less than 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing double values in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Well, how close do you need the value to be to 0? If you go through a lot of floating point operations which in "infinite precision" might result in 0, you could end up with a result "very close" to 0.

Typically in this situation you want to provide some sort of epsilon, and check that the result is just within that epsilon:

```
if (Math.Abs(something) < 0.001)
```

The epsilon you should use is application-specific - it depends on what you're doing.

Of course, if the result should be *exactly* zero, then a simple equality check is fine.

Comment: Actually, I need it to be exactly zero, how would that look?

I looked for Double.Zero, but know luck. There is a constant right?

Btw, thanks, I get the epsilon part now :)

Comment: @radbyx: Just use `== 0`. You've got a literal there - that's pretty constant :)

Answer (score 36):

If `something` has been assigned from the result of an operation other than `something = 0` then you better use:

```
if(Math.Abs(something) < Double.Epsilon)
{
//do something
}
```

*Edit*: This code is wrong.  Epsilon is the smallest number, but not quite zero.  When you wish to compare a number to another number, you need to think of what is the acceptable tolerance.  Let's say that anything beyond .00001 you don't care about.  That's the number you'd use.  The value depends on the domain.  However, it's mostly certainly never Double.Epsilon.

Comment: This doesn't solve the rounding problem, for example `Math.Abs(0.1f - 0.1d) < double.Epsilon` is `false`

Comment: Double.Epsilon is too small for such comparsion. Double.Epsilon is the smallest positive number that double can represent.

Comment: This makes no sense because it's practically the same as comparing against 0. -1

Comment: The goal is to compare against the concept of 0 without using == . At least it makes sens mathematically.

I am assuming you have a double at hand and you want to compare it to the concept of zero without ==. If your double is different from 0d for any reason, including rounding, the test fill return false.

This comparison seems valid for any double and will return true only if this double is smallest than the smallest number that can be represented, which seems a good definition for testing the concept of 0, no?

Comment: Nothing can be smaller than Double.Epsilon this expression is always false.

Comment: @MaurGi: you're wrong:

            `double d = Math.Sqrt(10100)*2;
            double a = Math.Sqrt(40400);
            if(Math.Abs(a - d) < double.Epsilon)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
            }`

Comment: @sonatique  Math.Abs(something) < Double.Epsilon evaluates to true only when something is exactly zero, in which case something == 0 would also be true, so why not just use that?

Comment: "Because Epsilon defines the minimum expression of a positive value whose range is near zero, the margin of difference between two similar values must be greater than Epsilon. Typically, it is many times greater than Epsilon. Because of this, we recommend that you do not use Epsilon when comparing Double values for equality." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s.aspx

Comment: You should never use Double.Epsilon for double comparison. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411392/double-epsilon-for-equality-greater-than-less-than-less-than-or-equal-to-gre

Answer (score 31):

Your `something` is a `double`, and you have correctly identified that in the line

```
if (something == 0)
```

we have a `double` on the left-hand side (lhs) and an `int` on the right-hand side (rhs).

But now it seems like you think the lhs will be converted to an `int`, and then the `==` sign will compare two integers. That's **not** what happens. The conversion *from* `double` *to* `int` is **explicit** and can not happen "automatically".

Instead, the opposite happens. The rhs is converted to `double`, and then the `==` sign becomes an equality test between two doubles. This conversion is implicit (automatic).

It is considered better (by some) to write

```
if (something == 0.0)
```

or

```
if (something == 0d)
```

because then it's immediate that you're comparing two doubles. However, that's just a matter of style and readability because the compiler will do the same thing in any case.

It's also relevant, in some cases, to introduce a "tolerance" like in Jon Skeet's answer, but that tolerance would be a `double` too. It **could** of course be `1.0` if you wanted, but it does not have to be [the least strictly positive] integer.

Answer (score 20):

If you simply want to suppress the warning, do this:

```
if (something.Equals(0.0))
```

Of course, this is only a valid solution if you know that drift isn't a concern. I often do this to check if I'm about to divide by zero.

Answer (score 5):

I dont' think it's equal, honestly. Consider yuor own example: something = 0.9, or 0.0004. 
In first case it will be FALSE, in second case it will be TRUE. Dealing with this types I usually define for me precision percentage and compare within that precision. 
Depends on your needs.
something like...

```
if(((int)(something*100)) == 0) {


//do something
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: something has to be exactly zero.

Comment: so you're lucky guy, in this case :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the example presenting the problem (prepared in LinQPad - if you don't have it just use `Console.Writeline` instead of `Dump` method):

```
void Main()
{
    double x = 0.000001 / 0.1;
    double y = 0.001 * 0.01; 

    double res = (x-y);
    res.Dump();
    (res == 0).Dump();
}
```

Both x and y are theoretically same and equal to: 0.00001 but because of lack of "infinite precision" those values are slightly different. Unfortunately slightly enough to return `false` when comparing to 0 in usual way.

Answer (score 3):

Prefer this method when you want to check how close is the double value to zero for both signs.

```
public bool IsZero(double value, double precision = 1E-6)
{
    return !double.IsNaN(value)
        && !double.IsInfinity(value)
        && Math.Abs(value) < precision;
}
```

Comment: There are **six existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **one hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Comment: This method considers how low is too low for a value to be considered zero.

Comment: Could be upgraded to `bool IsEqual(double value, double compareTo, double precision)`