# C#, DETERMINE *if* a double can become an int without any loss

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if a decimal/double is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751593/how-to-determine-if-a-decimal-double-is-an-integer)

I have a unique situation in which all numbers must be saved as `double` data type in my database, but only in certain conditions is the precision beyond the integer level valuable.

At first, I tried to just use `int` and then abstract to a new table when these unique fractional occurances would happen, but after doing that for weeks I can see now that it is excessively stupid and wasting my time.

I know that I can turn a `double` into an `int`. That is easy. I know how to translate it over. What I do not know is how to TEST for translating it over. I basically wish to come up with a short, easy way to say

> Is this number really a double, or is it just an int?

If it is an int (and most of the time, it will be), then I will turn it into one and treat it as such. But due to the uniqueness of the requirements, I have to still save everything in the database as `double`.

Any ideas? I know this is a newbie question, and I've googled around for several hours and am still left quite confused.

Comment: So wouldn't you just test if the incoming value is larger than the maximum integer value? Or are you more concerned if the value has a fractional part to it?

Comment: So is a price of $1.00 an `int` or `double` in this world? *Trick question: it's a `decimal`.*

Comment: What do you mean 'without any loss'?  Are you saying that 10.000 can be turned into 10 without loss, but 10.001 cannot?  In which case you need to define how big a loss is acceptable, as you cannot say 0.  You need to say +/- 0.001 or whatever.

Comment: As additional commentary, I'm not sure I like this approach, treating something as an integer because it might be a round number. That should not drive your logic. If something *should* be an integer, *then* treat it like one. If something happens to be a round number, but it really doesn't need to be an integer, treat it like the type it *should* be. Normally, the type should be consistent for all values in a given column. And you should make this determination at design time, not runtime.

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, this would be ideal, but this is not possible in my situation.

Comment: @iandotkelly: Yes, that is essentially what I am saying. `10.000` is the same as `10`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751593/how-to-determine-if-a-decimal-double-is-an-integer) shows you how to determine if a double or decimal has decimal places or not. You can use this to determine what type it is and then store appropriately.

Accepted answer from that post:

For floating point numbers, `n % 1 == 0` is typically the way to check if there is anything past the decimal point.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    decimal d = 3.1M;
    Console.WriteLine((d % 1) == 0);
    d = 3.0M;
    Console.WriteLine((d % 1) == 0);
}
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I forgot about the modulo command. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Cast it to an `int` and see if it's still equal:

```
if ((int)val == val)
```

`(int)val` will truncate any fractional portion.

Note that this may behave unexpectedly if the number is too large to retain complete precision in the `double`.

Comment: Would there be any advantage to using `Math.Truncate` instead of a cast?

Answer (score 9):

```
double d = ...;

if(d == (int)d)
   //is int
else
  //is not int
```

Of course due to some precision issues, this may not work 100% times. You can use

```
double d = ...;

if(Math.Abs(d - (int)d) < Epsilon) //const double Epsilon = 0.000001;
   //is int
else
  //is not int
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
double x = ......

if (Math.truncate(x) == x)

....... (is integer, unless its so big its outside the bounds)
```