# Logging logarithmically 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc

Tags: c#, .net, logarithm

Is there a more efficient way of doing the following, something just feels wrong about it?  I'm looking for the most time efficient way of logging logarithmically.

```
    public bool Read()
    {
        long count = Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        switch (count)
        {
            case 1L:
            case 10L:
            case 100L:
            case 1000L:
            case 10000L:
            case 100000L:
            case 1000000L:
            case 10000000L:
            case 100000000L:
            case 1000000000L:
            case 10000000000L:
            case 100000000000L:
            case 1000000000000L:
            case 10000000000000L:
            case 100000000000000L:
            case 10000000000000000L:
            case 100000000000000000L:
            case 1000000000000000000L:
                _logger.LogFormattable(LogLevel.Debug, $"{count} Rows Read");
                break;
        }

        return _reader.Read();
    }
```

Update:

Here are my micro benchmark tests.

- Method1: Übercoder's way with keep up with state
- Method2: My way with the big switch statement
- Method3: Markus Weninger's way with the nice Math Function

Since for me 100,000,000 records being read without logging takes around 20 minutes then an extra 4 seconds is nothing.  I'm going with the beautiful Math way of doing things.  Mathod3 wins in my scenario.

```
Run time for 100,000,000 iterations averaged over 100 attempts

Method1 Max: 00:00:00.3253789
Method1 Min: 00:00:00.2261253
Method1 Avg: 00:00:00.2417223

Method2 Max: 00:00:00.5295368
Method2 Min: 00:00:00.3618406
Method2 Avg: 00:00:00.3904475

Method3 Max: 00:00:04.0637217
Method3 Min: 00:00:03.2023237
Method3 Avg: 00:00:03.3979303
```

Comment: @Dai that is on floating point, which isn't the case here. Also the question is about c#, not c++. If you have a better, duplicate, let me know.

Comment: Using a `switch` statement like you do really is the fastest way to do this as it will be compiled into a series of processor-level hashtable instructions which are lightning fast. While the code is "ugly" (well, I think it's kind-of beautiful) I think you can improve it by moving it to a separate function (`IsExactlyPowerOf10(Int64 n)") and calling that from your `Read` function.

Comment: Thanks for the nice benchmarking of all the three methods :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If performance is not a big problem, I would use the following

```
if(Math.Log10(count) % 1 == 0)
  _logger.LogFormattable(LogLevel.Debug, $"{count} Rows Read");
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751593/how-to-determine-if-a-decimal-double-is-an-integer) states the following:

> For floating point numbers, n % 1 == 0 is typically the way to check if there is anything past the decimal point.

---

Edit: To complete my answer, it is also possible to keep track of the next logging value, as @Übercoder posted in his answer.

```
long nextLoggingValueForLogX = 1;
if (count == nextLoggingValueForLogX )
{
   nextLoggingValueForLogX *= 10; // Increase it by your needs, e.g., logarithmically by multiplying with 10
   _logger.LogFormattable(LogLevel.Debug, $"{count} Rows Read");
}
```

Yet this method will come up with a new variable for every log that shouldn't be executed every time. This will introduce extra code and also extra work if it has to be made thread-safe.

Comment: I will do a performance test of mine vs yours and see what comes out faster, I really hope it's your because it's much more beautiful.  Even if it's a little slower I will probably still use it.  Let me do some performance tests to see if I can mark this as the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also interested in this. I hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
static long logTrigger = 1;


if (count == logTrigger)
{
   logTrigger *= 10;
   // do your logging
}
```

Comment: I bet yours is the fastest, I'll let you know.  I would remove the static though from the trigger.

Comment: Yes, this will for sure be the fastest. But, on the other hand, it introduces a new variable for every log that should be executed logarithmically. That's the choice one has to make.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having to do a lot to make this thread safe too, since it's not.