# How to define a custom Validation for a property in DevExpress?

Tags: c#, validation, devexpress, xpo

Please consider that I have in an entity a property

```
        public double RealVolume
        {
            get
            {
                return _RealVolume;
            }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue("RealVolume", ref _RealVolume, value);
            }
        }
```

then I also have

```
        [Browsable(false)]
        public VolumeType VolumeOrVolumePoints
        {
            get
            {
                return WMSSystemSetting.Get_VolumeOrVolumePoints(Session);
            }
        }
```

I want that when `VolumeOrVolumePoints == VolumeType.Volume` then `RealVolume` to be validated as an integer otherwise validated as double number.

How could I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For information on how to validate an object with XPO, see [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/CustomDocument2063). If you happen to be using DevExpress XAF then use a `ValidationRule` from the *ValidationModule instead*.

So you need something like:

```
protected override void OnSaving() 
{
    if (VolumeOrVolumePoints == VolumeType.Volume)
    {
        if (RealVolume % 1 != 0) // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2751597/1077279
             throw new Exception("The RealVolume value must be an integer when using Volume units.");
    }
}
```