# Double or Integer in string?

Tags: c#, string, variables, integer, double

For example in a console application I have the following code:

```
Console.Writeline("Enter function");
string function = Console.Readline();
```

and then `function` gets defined as:

```
function = "ceil(5.0)";
```

then I would define the variable as a double.
But what if the user would enter:

```
function = "ceil(5)";
```

How can I do a check if there is a double filled in or an integer so I now how to store that variable. And also if its the same but then with negative numbers, I already tried regex but maybe I didn't do it right. Any ideas?

Comment: Modify the code parsing the function entered by the user to detect the presence of a decimal point? Surely, if you are able to write a function parser, that should be piece of cake for you?

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks i will look into that, but then if there is for example 5.0 its recognized as a double but it actually is an integer if you know what i mean

Comment: I know what you mean, but I would recommend to *still* use a double in that case: That's what most programming languages do if you use a literal such as `5.0`, and it would be confusing to change that convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For floating point numbers, n % 1 == 0 is typically the way to check if there is anything past the decimal point.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    decimal d = 3.1M;
    Console.WriteLine((d % 1) == 0);
    d = 3.0M;
    Console.WriteLine((d % 1) == 0);
}
```

Output:

```
False //is a double
True //is a integer
```

More information can be found at this page: 
[How to determine if a decimal/double is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751593/how-to-determine-if-a-decimal-double-is-an-integer)

Comment: I think the asker wants it the other way, check if string contains double or integer. You are checking if a double is a whole number or contains decimals.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using Regex, you could check for function+parenthesis+value+closing_parenthesis. Check this as a starting point:

```
ceil\((\-?\d{1,}(?:.\d{1,})?)\)
```

Please note that Regex allows negative numbers. If you don't want that, remove the **\-?** part.