# validating for int ONLY, what is the correct code for this code?

Tags: c#

```
 // if user input is negative
 if (h < 0)
 {
     // assign absolute version of user input
     number = Math.Abs(n);
     pictureBox14.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    // else assign user input
        number = n;
    number = 0; // if user input is not an int then set number to 0  
    pictureBox6.Visible = true;
}
```

What is the correct code for validating to int ONLY? That integer is the only one I want to input in the textbox then the picturebox will appear.

Comment: What are `h` and `n`? And I guess your looking for [`int.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: what is `n`? what is `number`? also what is `h`

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751593/how-to-determine-if-a-decimal-double-is-an-integer

Answer (score 0):

Use int.TryParse method

```
int value= 0;

        if (int.TryParse(n, out value))
        {
            if (value< 0)
                number = Math.Abs(value);
            else
                number = value;
        }
```

Comment: He uses already the numbers `h` and `n`, so i doubt that string conversion helps

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a complicated if statement. You can do it like this.

```
int number = 0;
bool isValid = int.TryParse(userInputString, out number);
number = Math.Abs(number);

if (isValid)
{
    pictureBox14.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: He uses already the numbers `h` and `n`, so i doubt that string conversion helps

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah, but he still asks how to validate only integers, which makes me think it might also help him.

Answer (score 0):

You first want to parse user Input, then validate the range:

```
int ExampleFunc( string userInput )
{
    int nVal;
    if( int.TryParse( userInput, out nVal ) )
    {
        return Math.Abs( nVal );
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: He uses already the numbers `h` and `n`, so i doubt that string conversion helps

Comment: @TimSchmelter He talks about getting a value from a TextBox, though.

Comment: @TimSchmelter See "number = 0; // if user input is not an int then set number to 0" how else would you deal with that comment? A variable that already is int cannot be "not int"  ... right?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to check if the number is negative, just always use the absolute value. `Convert` will return a 0 value if the string passed to it from the text input cannot be converted properly, so this code handles your question in just one line. If you want the picture box to show based on the int value, test that after the conversion.

```
int number = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(textInput));
```